# is there a way to know which Android OS versions are declare End-of-life by Google?

Tags: android

We need to determine which Android OS or API versions are declared end-of-life for one of our research projects.

MobSF, one of the Mobile security framework tools, suggests that Android 8 or API 26 can be supported at a minimum, and anything lesser than that can be harmful.

However, https://endoflife.date/android says that Android 10 support ended on 6 Mar 2023. That way, Android 8 is no longer safer.

We were researching for an official Google/Android statement for End-of-life of Android versions. Android Security Bulletin is a place to know but there are a lot of these bulletins available and it is hard to go through each one of them.

Is there a way to understand more about these?

Comment: I am not sure if Google have stated when support for each version ends, if you look at the [Android version history Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history) you can see the column "Latest security patch date" so I guess you have to go through all security bulletins and check when each version did received it's last update. Then you have each EOL date.